# How to make a reference type from int

Tags: c#, .net

i tried:

```
int i = 5;
object o1 = i; // boxing the i into object (so it should be a reference type)
object o2 = o1; // set object reference o2 to o1 (so o1 and o2 point to same place at the heap)

o2 = 8; // put 8 to at the place at the heap where o2 points
```

after running this code, value in o1 is still 5, but i expected 8.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Boxing doesn't change its type. It should remain a value type.

Comment: I don't think using object makes an int a reference type actually; it stores an undetermined type, but .NET maintains an understanding of what the object is (it knows it's an int, which isn't a reference type).

Comment: Boxed value types are immutable.  The assignment `o2 = 8;` creates a new boxed int and makes it the referent of `o2`.  The other variable, `o1`, still points to the first boxed int.  The same happens with strings: `string s1 = "5"; string s2 = s1; s2 = "8";` Indeed, the same happens with mutable reference types: `List<int> x = new List<int> { 5 }; List<int> y = x; y = new List<int> { 8 };`

Comment: Are you trying to duplicate the behavior of some other language?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's not how variables in C# work. It has nothing to do with boxing value types.

Consider this:

```
object o1 = new object();
object o2 = o1;

o2 = new object();
```

Why would you expect `o1` and `o2` to contain a reference to the same object? They are the same when you set `o2 = o1`, but once you set `o2 = new object()`, the value (the memory location pointed to by the variable) of `o2` changes.

Maybe what you're trying to do can be done like this:

```
class Obj {
    public int Val;
}

void Main() {
    Obj o1 = new Obj();
    o1.Val = 5;
    Obj o2 = o1;
    o2.Val = 8;
}
```

At the end of `Main`, the `Val` property of `o1` will contain `8`.

Answer (score 5):

To do what you want to do, the value has to be a property of a reference type:

```
public class IntWrapper
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public IntWrapper(int value) { Value = value; }
}

IntWrapper o1 = new IntWrapper(5);
IntWrapper o2 = o1;

o2.Value = 8;
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ken gives you perfect answer. This one is how to get same behavior with `struct` (value types).

**Note**: mutable value types have very non-intuitive behaviors, don't try this at home:).

To get similar behavior with value types you need to implement some interface and set property via interface because unboxing `struct` to its own type will always create copy and you'll not be able to modify original value.

```
void TortureMutableBoxedValueType()
{
  object o1 = new IntWrapper(5);
  object o2 = o1;
  Console.WriteLine(((IValue)o1).Value); // outputs original 5
  ((IValue)o2).Value = 8; 
  Console.WriteLine(((IValue)o1).Value); // outputs new 8
}

interface IValue 
{
  int Value {get;set;}
}

// Don't use mutable value types - this is just sample.
public struct IntWrapper : IValue 
{
  int v;
  public int Value { get { return v;} set {v = value;}}
  public IntWrapper(int value) { v = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Joel points out even though boxed it is still a value type and as such it is not referenced it is cloned. This is why you see this results - o1 and o2 point to different memory locations.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe unrelated, but if you are looking for an integer to work as a reference type (like passing the variable in some method and do some operation on it and keep the value after exiting the method), then you can use ref keyword. like so:

```
int index = 0;

SomeMethod(ref index);
```

where the method is like this:

```
public void SomeMethod(ref int parameter)
{
   parameter++;
}
```